# delete all folders except latest 3 or 3 folders in windows box

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, groovy

I want to write a batch file and call it through jenkins file. Through which I have to delete all folders in a location other than latest 3 folders.

Below code works fine when I run it manually.

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %G in ('dir /B /ad-h /o-d') DO echo going to delete %G
```

But when I keep this code in a batch file and run I am getting error. The location of folders I want to delete is stored in env variable ${BuildPathPublishRoot}.

Where to pass the env variable in code.  I don't want to delete any files in the location. I only want to delete folders.

Comment: 1. with `skip=2` you're going to keep the most recent **2** folders; 2. I'd also exclude system folders (`dir /B /A:D-H-S`); 3. in a batch file `%G` must be replaced by `%%G`; 4. you don't specify any target path, so you might actually work in another directory than you expect…

Comment: Did you try opening the Command Prompt, typing `for /?`, pressing the `[ENTER]` key, and reading the usage information? If you had you should have read, `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.`. Therefore try using `@For /F "Skip=3 EOL=| Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:D-H /O:-D 2^>NUL') Do @Echo Going to remove %%G` instead. BTW, if you're wanting to perform ther task within a known directory, and not the current working directory, you should insert that `<space>"D:\irectory Path"<space>` between `D` and `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help this is working. Kindly let me know what should I do if I need to exclude folder named "latest" from being deleted.

Comment: Place `if /I not "%%G"=="latest"` inside the body of the loop (between `do` and `echo`)…

Comment: by the way.. is `rmdir` not what you really need instead of `del`?

Comment: In the output screen I am getting this "rmdir /s /q 7" but in real its not deleting. When I tried this command manually it worked. Please help me to fix it

Comment: How about you use the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62714760/edit)** button, and update your question so that we are all aware of what you're now doing, what is happening when you run it, and what you want to happen instead. Trying to keep potential responder informaed in the comment section, is not likely to attract many willing helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer worked fine

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`. Therefore try using

```
@For /F "Skip=3 EOL=| Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:D-H /O:-D 2^>NUL') Do @Echo Going to remove %%G instead.
```

BTW, if you're wanting to perform the task within a known directory, and not the current working directory, you should insert that "D:\Directory Path" between D and 2.